# Math - Curve Optimizing, Filtering, Smoothing

Tags: c#, math, filtering, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have been working for some time on a software in C# to optimize the measuring points of a CNC milling machine for the repair of alloy wheels.
Unfortunately, I am not getting anywhere. The goal of the software is to analyze the measurement, to smooth the noise of the data, to interpolate curves and to remove measuring points in straight lines.

The original contour is to be retained. At last I applied the Savitzky-Golay filter and the Akima interpolation.
Unfortunately, the methods cannot be applied with one value over the whole curve, because this destroys the contour. Because of my lack of knowledge, it is not possible for me to automatically split the contour so that the procedures can be applied to individual segments.

An example that has to be optimized can look like this [image: example curve of CNC measurement points]

Manual selection of curve segments is unfortunately not an option, as the customer wants automation to be as complete as possible.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas that could help me.
Thank you very much for your effort.

[Edit]
I should mention that I am open if you know solutions in other languages, such as python.

Comment: i would probably suggest hiring someone who does know what they're doing.  Sounds harsh maybe but what you are describing requires a lot of specialist knowledge. Even if you got something working, how will you know its doing the right thing?

Comment: what i would suggest however, is doing some initial investigative work in excel maybe.  Plot some data and try and apply the methods you mention.  Find a way of proving those methods (are there any online web based implementations of those methods?).  Then once you have a proven method, you might then consider moving to coding it in C#

Comment: Finally read [ask] - ask a more specific question, show the code you've written, what you expect to happen and what is not happening

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately I can't post the code as it is a customer project. My point is to basically have an approach to continue working on. Maybe the experts you described are here and can give me some food for thought. It's not about me being lazy and not wanting to work it out myself. I just need mental support, because I'm at a point where I can't get ahead.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not how SO works - you need to post code.  Its possible to do that without causing issues with customer contracts.  Just pull out the bits you need help with.

Comment: it does sound like you need help more the method, not the code.  There are other stack exchange sites that may be better suited for your question (eg mathematical sites)

Comment: You are not really describing what the exact problem is. The posted points look quite smooth to me. If the goal is to reduce the number of points I usually use Ramer–Douglas–Peucker, but there are probably some more appropriate method for optimizing splines.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com, but anyway here are some notes.

My advice is to frame this as finding the best piecewise-continuous approximation. This is assuming that you know what pieces there might be. The problem is a nested search: given break points A and B (looks like there are just two, to judge by the picture), estimate the best-fitting curves over (0, A), (A, B), and (B, end). Now add up the errors for the three pieces and put that on a list, associated with (A, B).

Then repeat that for all possible pairs (A, B). That gives you a look up table: for each (A, B) pair, you know the total error assuming the break points. Now just search the table for the smallest total, and there you have it: the location of the break points associated with the smallest total error.